# failed to pull docker/whalesay from dockerhub,

Tags: docker

i have installed docker on ubuntu14.04-64bit,when i want to run a demo,error occurs,

```
y7:~$ docker run docker/whalesay cowsay boo
Unable to find image 'docker/whalesay:latest' locally
Repository docker/whalesay already being pulled by another client.  Waiting.
Error response from daemon: No such image: docker/whalesay (tag: latest)
7:~$ docker run docker/whalesay
Unable to find image 'docker/whalesay:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/whalesay

e9e06b06e14c: Pulling fs layer 
a82efea989f9: Pulling fs layer 
e9e06b06e14c: Error pulling dependent layers 
07f8e8c5e660: Pulling fs layer 
676c4a1897e6: Pulling fs layer 
5b74edbcaa5b: Pulling fs layer 
1722f41ddcb5: Pulling fs layer 
99da72cfe067: Pulling fs layer 
5d5bd9951e26: Pulling fs layer 
fb434121fc77: Download complete 
fb434121fc77: Pulling image (latest) from docker/whalesay, endpoint: https://regfb434121fc77: Error pulling image (latest) from docker/whalesay, endpoint: https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/, Server error: Status 0 whilefetching image layer (fb434121fc77: Error pulling image (latest) from  docker/whalesay, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer  (e9e06b06e14c2f7d8df0251e3bb852c3a10a70639498Error pulling image (latest)  from docker/whalesay, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer   (e9e06b06e14c2f7d8df0251e3bb852c3a10a70639498163d4f180a823c18fdfc)
```

Comment: Are you behind some firewall that might be preventing the download? Check your network as a first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Error response from daemon: No such image: docker/whalesay (tag: latest)` is a little confusing, but the real error is the line just above it:

```
Repository docker/whalesay already being pulled by another client.  Waiting.
```

If you begin pulling a repo and then <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, the Docker daemon will hang out for a while and refuse to do further pulls on that repo.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a system might require to have both a few local docker repos, as well as having docker images hosted on DockerHub. The best way to be assured that you are pointing the the DockerHub repo is to pull with

```
docker.io/<repo>/<app>
```

In your case, try

```
docker.io/docker/whalesay
```